# msbuild project with . in name

Tags: msbuild

I want to be able to build only one project in my solution using msbuild /t. The problem occurs when the project name includes a ".", for instance MyProject.Unittests

msbuild reports MSB4057, no matter what I write. I have tried escaping the . with %2e without any success.

I have a similar problem when the project is added to a solution folder with space in the name.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That should not be the issue. Can you share the full command that you use to build the project ?

Comment: I just found an old post explaining this :) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/263147/cant-use-msbuild-to-build-c-project-with-in-project-name